# Mongodb - arrayMerge specific fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

How can i use merge array to a new array from a detail document
there is an example of data

**Example of result detail**

```
[{
    country: 'USA',
    val: 500,
    items: [
        {val:50, ...manyFieldsToIgnore},
        {val:30, ...manyFieldsToIgnore},
        {val:110, ...manyFieldsToIgnore},
    ]
}];
```

**Output expected**

```
{ items:[ 
    {
        country: 'USA',
        newNameValue: 500,
    },
    {
        country: 'USA',
        newNameValue: 50,
    },
    {
        country: 'USA',
        newNameValue: 30,
    },
    {
        country: 'USA',
        newNameValue: 110,
    },
};
```

im try to use $project and $concatArrays but i dont know how to set the new field(country) in details and change their key names

```
$project: {
    'root.country': '$country',
    items: concatArrays[ '$items'],
},
$project: {
    payments: concatArrays[ '$items', ['$root'] ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following aggregation returns the desired result. Note the usage of the [Aggregation Array Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators) - `$map` and `$concatArrays`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { 
      $addFields: {
          items: { 
             $map: { 
                 input: "$items", 
                 in: { country: "$country", newNameVal: "$$this.val"  } 
             }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          items: { 
              $concatArrays: [ [ { country: "$country", newNameVal: "$val" } ],  "$items" ]
          } 
      }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `$addFields` to add country in items array
- `$project` to concat 2 arrays one is outer val and country and second is items array using `$concatArrays`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { "items.country": "$country" } },
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              val: "$val",
              country: "$country"
            }
          ],
          "$items"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MQ2tK5pRB6M)